# What is the difference between tags and metadata in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, tags

What is the difference between use case for metadata and tags in SharePoint?

Is the tags feature now deprecated?

How to setup these such that they can be used at:

1. Document library level (for that doc library only)
2. Site level (for all doc libraries in the site)
3. Global level (for all doc libraries across all sites)